# How do I pass a bundle to another fragment using getFragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a nav fragment and a content fragment. I want to be able to pass a bundle, and reload the fragment based on fragment interactions. I've seen people say use `.setArguments()`, but it's not letting me use said method. Any advice?

```
public void onStockFragmentInteraction(String stock) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("stock", stock);

    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content, new StoryFragment())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setArguments` is a method of `Fragment` not of `FragmentManager`

```
StoryFragment f = new StoryFragment() 
f.setArguments(bundle);

getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content, f)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

keep a reference to the fragment and call `setArguments` on the instance before submitting it on the transaction

Comment: Thank you! That was the key piece I was missing.